# signalR hub with Ocelot Gateway

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, ocelot

I created a dummy solution then tried to connect MVC client with signalR hub through Ocelot Api gateway.

ocelot works well with other http/https endpoints, but not so with signalR websocker

MVC client port => 5010

ocelot gateway  => 5006

signalR hub     => 5008

```
{
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/WeatherForecast",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 5003
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/WeatherForecast",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get" ]
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/{catchAll}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "ws",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 5008
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/hub/{catchAll}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS" ]
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:5006"
  }
}
```

ocelot project startup.cs

```
    app.UseWebSockets();
    app.UseOcelot().Wait();
```

**you can check the solution on** Github
[HERE](https://github.com/ayman9hd/dummyOcelotSignalR.git)

I got this error

Ocelot.Responder.Middleware.ResponderMiddleware[0]
requestId: 0HM6825K74EEF:0000000F, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: Error Code: ConnectionToDownstreamServiceError Message: Error connecting to downstream service, exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
---> System.IO.IOException: The response ended prematurely.
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync(Boolean async)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync(Boolean async, Boolean foldedHeadersAllowed)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Ocelot.Requester.HttpClientHttpRequester.GetResponse(HttpContext httpContext) errors found in ResponderMiddleware. Setting error response for request path:/hub/negotiate, request method: POST